# Displaying a list of items with a template in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

My controller is querying a database. The results are returned in a `DataTable`. I want to display each `DataRow` of the `DataTable` in my `view`. In my `controller`, I have the following:

```
DataTable results = QueryDatabase();
ViewBag.Results = results;
```

I'm using `RAZOR` syntax in my `ASP.NET` `MVC` `view`. However, I'm not sure how to iterate through the rows and render each record. What is the recommended approach for doing this kind of task?

Comment: Really? `DataTable` in asp.net-mvc4? Dude, upgrade your DAL tier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set the viewbag to rows instead of the table, so `ViewBag.Results = results.Rows;`

Then to iterate through the rows use:

```
@foreach(DataRow row in ViewBag.Results)
{
    <div>@row["column_name"].ToString()</div>    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Grid helper from the [MvcContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/) package. Then you can do something like

```
@Html.Grid(ViewBag.Results.Rows).Columns(column => 
{
    column.For(r => r["column1"]);
    column.For(r => r["column2"]);
    ...
})
```

That will generate all the table stuff for you you prefer not to hand-code the HTML.